# Introductory material for creating file formats and doing serialization with C++

Tags: c++, serialization, file-format

I am looking for a good short overview about things that are important when serializing data to files. What techniques exist to deal with later changes in data structures? Are there certain header structures that are commonly used?

Specifically for C++: What library is appropriate for such tasks? Boost.Serialization?

EDIT: If possible, please provide a link that contains some answers!

Thanks for any hints,

Philipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is the choice of format:

- is it an internal/external file?
- is it just used as temporary storage, or does it need to be edited/processed?
- are there any speed or storage space concerns?

Once you have the format, you need to think about things like versioning:

- is backward-only compatibility OK, or do you need forward compatibility?
- do you need this at all?

And then you can think about libraries:

- various XML libraries
- Boost.Serialization
- s11n

Comment: Wooh! That's a very good list of questions indeed. I would suggest some other libraries though: Json libraries to replace Xml (much easier to edit manually, xml entities suck) and Google Protocol Buffers (because it's so good to be able to see the content with a Python script). Especially for long term storage, I definitely prefer Google Protocol Buffers: if you suddenly change your Business Model, you lose the one-one mapping object-blob, protobuf emphasizes this from scratch since you have a layer of adapters to go through.

Comment: I have read the very interesting description of s11n (http://s11n.net) and it seems very good indeed. I only wish there was a json serializer shipped with it for completeness. It seems light-weight yet has a dream-like feature list. My only two concerns would be the lazy loading, but this only concerns big files, and of course the mapping object-serializedblob that plagues all serialization framework (but that's what serialization is about). Very interested indeed, thank you!

Comment: Of particular note about s11n: deep serialization and cycle handling. That is quite awesome.